# MVC Checkboxlist only 1 item in postback

Tags: html, forms, post, model-view-controller, checkbox

I have a List of Checkboxes in my Website. The source of the Items is from the database.

```
@{
      dbEntities db = new dbEntities();

      foreach (var p in db.Product.ToList().OrderBy(o => o.Name))
      { 
          <input type="checkbox" name="chkProducts" class="chkclass" value="@p.ProductID" id="@p.ProductID"> @p.Name <br />
      } 
}
```

When i check for example 5 checkboxes, the result in the FormController has only one item in the "string[] chkProducts".

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Anfrage(FormCollection collection, string[] chkProducts)
{
        var checkedItems = collection["chkProducts"];
```

Why is in checkedItems everytime only one Item from 5 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you need to use brackets `[]` for the input name :

```
foreach (var p in db.Product.ToList().OrderBy(o => o.Name))
      { 
          <input type="checkbox" name="chkProducts[]" class="chkclass" value="@p.ProductID" id="@p.ProductID"> @p.Name <br />
                                       // HERE-----^
      }
```

Comment: Can you check your browser console if there is any errors.

Comment: Error: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[name=chkProducts[]]

Comment: when i set checkbox name to ( name="'chkProducts[]'" ) with ' then i can check the checkbox but string[] chkProducts is null...

Comment: There it is, you need to fix it by adding a single quotes : `$("input[name='chkProducts[]']")`